# Publish asp.net 3.5 website to local folder using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msbuild

I have a solution with multiple class libraries and a website (not a web application) in framework 3.5 VS 2008.

I would like to create a script/batch file to automate the publishing of the website to a given folder location(not to IIS).

I tried googling regarding this but everywhere they are refering to a .csproj file for the website. In my solution I do not have any such file for the website.

I do not want to use any add ons / other tools for automated builds right now.

Please suggest an approach using MSBuild or any other inbuilt asp.net tool.

Comment: Since you don't have a .csproj file and it's a website, you can just use MSBuild to compile the class libraries, then have your script copy the website (and .dlls) into a folder of your choosing. It should be pretty straightforward, particularly if you follow a tutorial for using MSBuild on class libraries. What in particular did you need help with?

Comment: I cannot remember when it was introduced but cannot you use the built-in Publish feature to deploy your web site to a local folder?